# Highlight right answer after selecting wrong cell in Swift with didSelectRowAt(_:)

Tags: ios, swift

I have quiz app that uses a table view with cells containing a label, which I reuse using `dequeueReusableCell`. Now, when the user clicks on a wrong answer, the label should turn red and it should show me right answer highlighting the right answer label with green background at the same time. All of this should take place in `didSelectRowAt(_:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should control the background of the cells in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` function. After a cell is pressed, you should reload the table view if the right answer is not shown yet.

```
var shouldShowRightAnswer = false

let rightAnswer = 0
var selectedAnswer: Int?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    [...]

    if shouldShowRightAnswer {
        if indexPath.row == rightAnswer {
            cell.backgroundColor = .green
            cell.textLabel.textColor = .white
        } else if indexPath.row == selectedAnswer {
            cell.backgroundColor = .white
            cell.textLabel.textColor = .red
        }
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        cell.textLabel.textColor = .black
    }

    [...]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if !shouldShowRightAnswer {
        selectedAnswer = indexPath.row
        shouldShowRightAnswer = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than reloading all the cells in a table view it's usually better to only reload the ones that you've changed using `reloadRows(at:with:)`

Comment: This won't work for me as I am getting the right answers from API and has a string value which I can convert into Int value while checking in the if condition.

Comment: @AjinkyaSonar I'm afraid I don't understand that. What prevents you from using this method?

Comment: Yes, It's working but at the same time. Even my next questions are marked as red and green. I need to apply this logic to individual questions and when the user swipes the next question is to be displayed and similar logic must perform after a cell is clicked.

Comment: You should make `shouldShowRightAnswer` false before displaying the next question.

Comment: Thank You so much. I am so happy that it's working like charm. As you said make shouldShowrRightAnswer false... You nailed it, Tamas. :)